# Вывод массива в haml

Tags: perl

Ребят как правильно вывести массив - так как пишу -получается ссылка на массив.

```
%td
%select ( name="moor" )
     - foreach my $moor ( @{$moors} ) {
        %option #{$moor}
     - }
 error =  an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at - r
```

Подскажите, какие варианты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А где здесь перл? Тут синтаксис какого-то шаблонизатора.

```
foreach my $moor (@$moors) {
    warn $option{$moor};
}
```

Comment: работаю с perl (morbo) - вывод haml, в селекте вывести массив значений,












,

Comment: ну, корректную перловую часть я вам написал

Comment: да ,она отработала - вывело на экран рядом с селектом :)  как впихнуть и вывести в селекте так пока и не придумал

Comment: зачем придумывать если есть документация и [поисковик][1]?

  [1]: https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=haml%20loop